# Change in percentiles over time

Tags: panel-data, quantiles

I feel like I am missing something basic here, but I can't figure the right way to analyze these data. A survey was done on patients at discharge in a large number of hospitals once a month for 6 months. The data for the hospital I am interested in are recorded only in percentile of the  large sample (and the N for the particular hospital).  An intervention was done in months 4, 5 and 6 and the goal is to evaluate the effect of the intervention.

What to do? Simply modeling percentile as a function of time doesn't seem like it uses all the information (in particular, it doesn't take account of sample size).

UPDATE: Thanks for the input, even if no ideal solution was found. Midway through, my client decided to not do any statistical analysis at all.  But the question is still interesting and I have to think it will come up again.

Comment: One percentile per hospital, or one per patient?

Comment: I believe what was done is that the scores of patients in each hospital were averaged and that turned into a percentile of all hospitals. So it is one percentile per hospital.

Comment: Please clarify.  Is the patient level data interval?  Do you have percentiles corresponding to the means of the patient data for each month & hospital?  Can you convert the percentile data into the corresponding mean on the patient data?  If so, and since you have the number underlying the means, if you could get an estimate of the error variance of the patient level data, you might be able to compare the means for intervention months versus the means for non-intervention months with a simple t test for the particular hospital you are interested in. (This assumes new patients each month.)

Comment: I can't convert the percentiles to means. I just have the percentiles for each month, but I don't know the underlying distribution for each month (and it could be different from month to month).  Whether percentiles themselves are interval level data is an interesting question.

Comment: The hospitals converted the means to percentiles. So can you use the same system in reverse to convert the percentiles to means?

Comment: Except I don't know which means correspond to which percentiles. And the same mean could be a different percentile in different months.

Comment: The hospitals converted the means to percentiles.  Can the hospitals simply tell you how they did that?  Why should the conversion process vary by month?  Are you saying that the patient level data was converted to percentiles and the percentiles were averaged?  In any case, do the hospitals have the patient level data available for you to use?

Comment: I don't have that information. I am not sure if I can get it. It will vary by month by small amounts simply because some months have patients who are more satisfied than other months.

Comment: Do you know if the number of hospitals was the same in all six months?  If not, that would be an added complication!

Comment: Can you clarify how the percentile reflects patient satisfaction? Do you have the patient satisfaction question(s)?  Do you know the percentiles that correspond to various points on the satisfaction question(s)?  If you do not, surely the hospitals must.

Comment: I believe it was the same number of hospitals.  I have the patient satisfaction questions, but I don't know more than that.

Comment: How did the hospitals go about determining the percentile score that corresponds to a mean patient satisfaction?  Did they apply the percentiles norms for individual satisfaction scores to the satisfaction means. Or did they determine a percentile score for each patient and then average those percentile scores? Or what?

Comment: They compared scores across hospitals.

Comment: So the hospitals have (or had) the raw data each month, or at least the means, for each of the hospitals. It seems you do not have access to those data.  If you did, you could determine the underlying score means for the hospitals, particularly for the hospital in question.  You could also estimate the error variance from the non-treatment months. With both, you could compute a test statistic.  It seems that approach is not an option.

Comment: Perhaps you could analyze the percentile data that you do have, using a non-parametric approach since the percentiles are not normally distributed. Although percentiles are not scores we usually use in calculating statistical tests, there is information in the percentiles, so a statistical test on the percentiles should have some meaning.

Comment: What did you end up doing? How did you analyze the data?

Comment: See my edit to the problem.

Comment: So the reason you cannot use Cochran's *Q* test for association between hospital and probability of outcome (like a repeated measures ANOVA for dichotomous outcomes), is because of missing information within subjects, within hospitals or both?